# Loading Textarea with Javascript on click event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a project which requires status update. I would like to add onlcick even on select box to show textarea only if the users selected the status as pending.

```
echo "
<select onchange=\"window.location=this.value\" name=\"status\">
    <option value=\"".$res1['ProjStatus']."\">".$res1['ProjStatus']."</option>
    <option value=\"completed\">Completed</option>
    <option value=\"ongoing\">Ongoing</option>
    <option value=\"Project.php?pending=pending\">Pending</option>
</select>
";
```

Question: I would like to show the textarea only if the user change the project status to pending.

The above code work but this refresh the whole page

Comment: you can show or hide anything according to the select because you reload the page as soon as it changes.

Comment: it is happening because of `onchange=\"window.location=....`. Remove that and put something appropriate.

Comment: do you want jump to (Project.php?pending=pending) page and not (ongoing) and (completed)??

Comment: This is inside PHP \ is escape charector

Comment: no i want to display textarea only when user selected pending as status

Comment: If you're refreshing the page for every selected value, there's no way to do with only `onchange` event, you can do it with `php` unless you're not refreshing or changing the page for the `Pending` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this. Forgive me for not testing that it works as is. Hopefully you can extrapolate.

HTML

```
<style> #textArea { display: none } </style>
<!-- select onchange calls javascript function to check if Pending was selected -->
<select onchange="toggleText(this.value)">
    <option value="<?php echo $res1['ProjStatus'] ?>"><?php echo $res1['ProjStatus'] ?></option>
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="ongoing">Ongoing</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
</select>

<textarea id='textArea' />
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleText(value) {
    // if the new value of the select element is Pending, show it
    if("Pending" === value){
        document.getElementById('textArea').style.display = "block";
        // the return values just lets you know the result if you ever need it
        return true; 
    }
   document.getElementById('textArea').style.display = "none";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That what i want but the textarea is always visible using your code

Comment: @user3811350 just use css (textarea { display:none; }) delete (document.getElementById('textArea').style.display = "none";) and change (document.getElementById('textArea').style.display = "show";) to (document.getElementById('textArea').style.display = "block";)

Comment: that works one drawback if the i select completed the textarea is still visible